# Explain this Error when using an int as base class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I know that it is wrong to do this, but I try to understand what is going on behind the scenes (and if you could potentially duck-type a class for extending it). The code is as follows:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> class C(a):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm trying to understand why `int()` would be called in this example. It is the type of `a` but I don't get why that is important here.

Comment: You're not using `int` as a base class, you're trying to use *an integer* as the base class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nono, I know it is "wrong", I'm interested in what and why this is happening

Comment: It's trying to call `type(2)` (`int`) instead of `type(int)` (`type`), and `int` doesn't have the same signature as `type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to inherit from an *instance object*, an integer object. Python treats `type(a)` as the *metatype*. The metatype is passed the class name, a tuple of the baseclasses and the body of the class as a dictionary; it is expected to produce the new class object.

In this case, that means `type(2)('C', (2,), {})` is called:

```
>>> type(2)('C', (2,), {})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Normally, that'd be the [`type()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) itself:

```
>>> type('C', (object,), {})
<class '__main__.C'>
```

where I used `object` as a base class instead.

See [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) for everything you didn't want to know about how metaclasses work in Python.

Comment: so if I get this right, I would be able to "inherit from an instance" if the type of that object behaves like a metaclass, correct?

Comment: @WorldSEnder well, yes - `int` is an instance of `type`, for example!

Comment: @WorldSEnder: yes, and all classes are *normally* instances of a metaclass, directly from `type` or a subclass of `type`.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically doing this:

```
class C(2):
    pass
```

As far as I am aware, you cannot inherit from an instance of object in this fashion.

You want to do:

```
class C(int):
    pass
```

OR

```
class C(type(a)):
    pass
```

Comment: Although this is correct, it doesn't actually answer the question the OP is asking